# Como utilizar a escolha do form select na página html

Tags: php, html, html-select

Preciso saber o que o usuário escolheu dentro de um `<select>`.

No código abaixo eu preciso saber qual o código da coleta escolhida pelo usuário, para assim mostrar os itens que ainda não foram coletados.

```
<p align="left">Nº da Coleta <br>
<?php 
      echo ("<select name=\"colCodigo\">");

      $coletas = new Coletas();
      $coletas = $coletas->distinct();

      foreach ($coletas as $c) 
      {
          $cod = $c["colCodigo"];

          echo ("<option>$cod</option>");
      }
      echo ("</select>");
?>
```

Comment: Nesse código nenhuma parte serve para saber qual o escolhido.

Comment: Você precisa colocar um `value` no seu `option`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supondo que sua tabela tenha um `id` para cada coleta, seu código deveria ficar assim:

```
<p align="left">Nº da Coleta <br>
<?php 
      echo ("<select name=\"colCodigo\">");

      $coletas = new Coletas();
      $coletas = $coletas->distinct();

      foreach ($coletas as $c) 
      {
          $cod = $c["colCodigo"];

          echo ("<option value='".$c["id"]."'>$cod</option>");
      }
      echo ("</select>");
?>
```

Assim, quando seu formulário for enviado poderá pegar o `value` do `select`.

Supondo que seja enviado via `POST` poderá pegar assim: `$valor=$_POST['colCodigo'];`

Comment: Ou pode usar o próprio "cod": `echo ("<option value='$cod'>$cod</option>");`. Assim a variável `$valor` (no momento de ler o `$_POST`) já terá o valor original do atributo **colCodigo**.